# ffmpeg headers not found while configuring ffmpeg-php

Tags: ffmpeg, php, centos-6, extension

I am configuring ffmpeg-php in a cpanel installed centos 6.8 server.

I was able to successfully install all necessary packages that were required to install ffmpeg.

Also I had successfully converted a video from one format to other.

```
[root@server ~]# ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-81056-g134fe28-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-decoder=liba52 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
libavcodec     57. 50.100 / 57. 50.100
libavformat    57. 43.100 / 57. 43.100
libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
```

The next step was to configure ffmpeg-php

I followed this procedure

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/ffmpeg-php/ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2
Untar this package, build and install it with following commands:
tar xjf ffmpeg-php-0.6.0.tbz2
cd ffmpeg-php-0.6.0
sed -i ‘s/PIX_FMT_RGBA32/PIX_FMT_RGB32/g’ ffmpeg_frame.c
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

Then I made changes to `/usr/local/lin/php.ini` as following

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20020429"
```

and added this following line to bottom of php.ini file

```
extension=ffmpeg.so
```

The real problem happens while executing ./configure I get this error and I cannot proceed further.

```
[root@server ffmpeg-php-0.6.0]# ./configure
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... re2c
checking for re2c version... 0.13.6 (ok)
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for ffmpeg support... yes, shared
checking whether to force gd support in ffmpeg-php... no
checking for ffmpeg headers... 
configure: error: ffmpeg headers not found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the --enable-shared option
```

Additionally

```
[root@server ffmpeg-php-0.6.0]# make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
[root@server ffmpeg-php-0.6.0]# make install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Comment: I getting same error with php5.6 on centos, How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score -2):

Try configure

```
./configure --with-ffmpeg=/usr/local/cpffmpeg
```

Comment: At what point in the process is this to occur? What will this do? How does it resolve the problem as described by OP?